# JsonHttpParser is deprecated

Tags: android, google-api, deprecated, google-places

I am building simple Android app where I am getting nearest locations using Goolge Places API. For this I used [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-api-client-android2). But when I am calling:

```
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
```

it is saying **The type JsonHttpParser is deprecated** by placing a line-through on this line in Eclipse, but app is still working.

My Question is - **Is it good using the libraries which are deprecated in application. Will this raise any problem in the future ?**

**EDIT:**

I used JsonHttpParser for creating HttpRequestFactory like:

```
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("Places-Test");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                // here it is saying deprecated
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Is there any alternative to create HttpRequestFactory?**

Answer (score 4):

**Definition of Deprecated**: A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

You can still use deprecated code without performance being changed, but the whole point of deprecating a method/class is to let users know there's now a better way of using it, and that in a future release the deprecated code is likely to be removed.

Deprecation today means that bugs will not be fixed tomorrow, unless you do it yourself.

If you do not mind that, then no need to worry.

Comment: Thank you. I added another question below it. Could you check once.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Class JsonHttpParser and Method HttpRequest were both deprecated in version 1.11. See [The Deprecated list](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.10.2-beta/deprecated-list.html) for more information.

If you want to replace the Deprecated JsonHttpParser, instead of:

```
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.addParser(parser);
```

Try:

```
            JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.setParser(parser);
```

And import:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser;
```

Note: Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be answer to question.

But in **google-http-client-1.5.0-beta.jar** library the deprecation is removed and JacksonFactory
class is also available.